# Smooth textured line with OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, drawing, opengl-es-2.0, shader

We have an iOS drawing app. Currently, the drawing is implemented with OpenGL ES 1.1. We use some algorithms to smooth the lines such as Bezier curves. So, when touch events occur, we get some set of points out of touch event points (based on algorithms) and draw these points. We also use brush texture for points to have more natural look.

I wonder if it's possible to implement these algorithms in OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders. Something like to call an OpenGL function to draw lines made of touch points and on output have smoothed brush-textured curve rendered.

[image]

Points P0, P1, ... P4 here are touch events and the points on red curve - output points, with such step for T so that the distance between two neighbor points on curve is not greater than 1 pixel.

And here is the link with Bezier algorithm explanation:
[Bézier curve - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? We can't tell you whether it's possible to implement a particular algorithm in a shader if we don't know what the algorithm is!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what algorithm we use. The point here is that the shader should produce more points on output than input points. I have edited my question and added an example with Bezier algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot generate new vertices inside the vertex shader (you can do it in the geometry shader, which ES doesn't have). The number of output vertices is always the same as the number of input vertices, you can only change their positions (and ohter attributes of course).

So you would have to draw a line strip made out of enough vertices to guarantee a smooth enough curve. What you can do is put in always the same line strip, having the curve parameter values T as 1D vertex positions. In the shader you then use this input position (the parameter value) to compute the actual 2D/3D position on the curve using the DeCasteljau algorithm (or whatever) and the points P0 to P4 which you put into the shader as constants (uniform variables in GLSL terms).

But I'm not sure if that would really buy you anything over just computing those points on the CPU and putting them into a dynamic VBO. What you save is the copying of the curve points from CPU to GPU and the computation on the CPU, but on the other hand your vertex shader is much more complex. It needs to be evaluated which is the better approach. If you need to compute the curve points each frame (because the control points change each frame) and the curve is rather high detail, it might not be that bad an idea. But otherwise I don't think it really pays. And also your shader won't be adaptable that easily to a changing number of control points/curve degree at runtime.

But once again, you cannot put in 5 control points and generate N curve points on the GPU. The vertex shader always works on a single vertex and results in a single vertex, the same as the fragment shader always works on a single fragment (say pixel, though it isn't one yet) and result in a single (or no) fragment.

Comment: Thanks for very comprehensive answer!
I was looking for a way to make the code clearer and also gain some performance. But, as I see, this is not the case.
By the way, you suggested very interesting approach, passing 1D line which represents T. I will think around it.